# Add on click for External link in wicket apache

Tags: java, wicket

I am quite new in Wicket Apache and have an old version 1.4.23

Have the following :

```
     private void addAgreementLink() {
      ExternalLink externalLink = new ExternalLink("lnkAgreement",
        new PropertyModel<String>(this, "pageAgreementURL"));
      this.add(externalLink);
    }
```

As you can see the following code is working, but I would like to add onClick method, so I can do some function after I click the link , How I can achieve this?

Anyone can help ?

After getting help from the great guys here, I am able to navigate to an external page and remove the message for the link from the server side, but It still appears when I go back from the broswer.

I will share my code here :

```
class PatronInfoAgreementContainer extends WebMarkupContainer {
   private final AgencyUserHelper agencyUserHelper;
  private final PatronInfoPage patronInfoPage;
  private final String markupId;

  PatronInfoAgreementContainer(final String id, PatronInfoPage 
  patronInfoPage, final AgencyUserHelper agencyUserHelper) {
    super(id);
    this.agencyUserHelper = agencyUserHelper;
    this.patronInfoPage = patronInfoPage;
    setOutputMarkupId(true);
    markupId = this.getMarkupId();
    }

   @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize();
    addAgreementLink();
     }

     private void addAgreementLink() {

    AjaxLink<String> agreementLink = new AjaxLink<String> 
         ("lnkAgreement") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
            if (ajaxRequestTarget != null) {
                ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavascript("jQuery(\"#" + 
                 markupId + "\").hide();");
                agencyUserHelper.setAgreementReminderShown(false);
                throw new 
          RedirectToUrlException(getPageAgreementURL());
              }
         }
       };
       this.add(agreementLink);
    }

       public String getPageAgreementURL() {
            return patronInfoPage.getPageAgreementURL();
          }

              @Override
             public boolean isVisible() {
             return agencyUserHelper.isSignAgreement() && 
        agencyUserHelper.agreementReminderShown();
            }
            }
```

The appendJavascript  is not working after I added throw new RedirectToUrlException line

any idea

Answer (score 2):

You could add `onclick="doSomething()"` in the markup:

```
<a wicket:id="lnkAgreement" onclick="doSomething()"></a>
```

This will do something on the client side.

If you need to do something on the server side then use `Link` instead of `ExternalLink`

```
  add(new Link<Void>("lnkAgreement") {
     @Override
     public void onClick() {
        doSomething();
        throw new RedirectToUrlException(pageAgreementURL);
     }
  });
```

Comment: I added the following:   


    private void addAgreementLink() {
        Link link = new Link("lnkAgreement",
                new PropertyModel<String>(this, "pageAgreementURL")) {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                isVisible = false;
            }
        };
        this.add(link);
    }

---------------------------------------------------------------------
But I got : 


Raw use of parameterized class 'Link' 
Unchecked call to 'Link(String, IModel<T>)' as a member of raw type 'org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link'

Comment: It's just a warning. In his example you can see that he is using `Link<Void>` indicating that the `modelObject` is of type `Void`. (Void is just a placeholder for the `void` keyword indicating that `modelObject` is null). In your case you probably want to use Link<String> as you are trying to pass the URL as a string to the Link.

Comment: Thanks, @magicmn! @Hani: what's the point of making something invisible while you navigate away from the page anyway ?

Comment: Because, we the user go back to the page , will see the message and the link which I do not want

Comment: In that case you need to store a record (e.g. in DB) that the user has viewed the agreement. Otherwise if the user visits a new instance of that page then `isVisible` will be `true`.

Comment: I did that and it works now, thank you Martin

Comment: Hi again, sorry for many questions regarding this but, now it works as I wanted but when I  go back from the browser the massage is still appeared, if I refresh the page the message disappears.

Comment: That's probably related to page versioning. If you have a stateful page Wicket automatically appends an `?{number}` to the url. So if the user presses the back button he gets the page in the state it was before leaving the side. I think you can turn it off by calling `setVersioned(false)`.

Comment: You could also use a Cookie instead of a db entry, depending on the use case. If the user has to log in to see the page in the first place a db entry is more reliable. The advantage of a cookie is that you don't need the user to log in.

Comment: Thank you, I am stuck at the browser issue , when I go back I get the component shown,I will update the original post so you understand what I mean

Comment: Using JavaScript to hide it, then navigating away to another page and then returning to the first page won't work. You need logic that is executed at page loading that checks whether the user has seen the agreement or not. That logic could use a Cookie, localStorage or a database.